# Reciprocal space in the context of x-ray diffraction and a crystal lattice?

Tags: crystallography

Could someone please explain what reciprocal space means in the context of of x-ray diffraction of a crystal lattice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unit cell space and reciprocal space are fourier transforms of each other. The unit cell indicates the stacking space between crystal elements. The reciprocal space is a similar kind of vectorial representation of the diffracted X-rays. The following reference explains it quite well, although it is not a simple concept. Unless you are smarter than me, you may have to read it 2 or 3 times to 'get it'.

[Reciprocal Lattices and Diffraction](http://bama.ua.edu/~mweaver/courses/MTE583/MTE%20583_Class_17a.pdf)